# I want to fetch all API data from data.gov.in it is only fetching 10 data

Tags: php, node.js, api

I'm using data.gov.in dataset API with the following link,
https://api.data.gov.in/resource/9ef84268-d588-465a-a308-a864a43d0070?api-key=579b464db66ec23bdd000001cdd3946e44ce4aad7209ff7b23ac571b&format=json&offset=0

This link is only fetching 10 records I've tried to add a limit parameter at the end of the link but it is still not showing all records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to call the function repeatedly, specifying a new offset each time. It looks like this particular API will only return a maximum of 10 records.

If you try setting the limit parameter to 5, for example it works but with 10 or greater you will only get 10 records.

e.g.

```
https://api.data.gov.in/resource/386ce542-8e39-4c4c-98e0-ddc28c2b5c56?api-key=579b464db66ec23bdd000001cdd3946e44ce4aad7209ff7b23ac571b&format=json&offset=1&limit=5
```

If you call the API repeatedly, increasing offset each time (e.g. +1), you'll get a list of records 10 at a time.

e.g.

```js
function getData(offset,limit) {

    fetch('https://api.data.gov.in/resource/386ce542-8e39-4c4c-98e0-ddc28c2b5c56?api-key=579b464db66ec23bdd000001cdd3946e44ce4aad7209ff7b23ac571b&format=json&offset=' + offset + '&limit=' + limit).then(response => {
         return response.json();
    }).then(json => {
       console.log(`Data length from offset #${offset}: `, JSON.stringify(json).length);
    });
}

// Call for a few offsets.
let offsets = [0,1,2,3,4];

offsets.forEach(offset => getData(offset, 10));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using sample api key. Register using your email and phone number and get your api key. You can get as many result you wish.

Comment: It is working for me Kunal. It should work for you as well. I got 10000 result in json format. Here is my video on same : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=93yfQFKAu-k

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python then here is the code other wise the concept is to first get the data count which the API key returns itself if you run this code
Note: Use your own API key which you can get by registering to the data.gov.in and put it in place of < YOUR API KEY HERE >

```
 import requests
 response = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.in/resource/3b01bcb8-0b14-4abf-b6f2-c1bfd384ba69?api-key=< YOUR API KEY HERE >&format=json&limit=1')
 data = eval(response.text)
 total_count = eval(response.text)['total']
```

then pass the total_count as variable in again in new response:

```
new_response = requests.get('https://api.data.gov.in/resource/3b01bcb8-0b14-4abf-b6f2-c1bfd384ba69?api-key=< YOUR API KEY HERE >&format=json&limit=%s'%total_count)

new_data = eval(new_response.text)
print (len(new_data['records']))
print (new_data['total'])
```